# Combination and Multiplying Rows of array in matlab

Tags: matlab, performance, combinatorics, binary-data, bitwise-and

I have a matrix (89x42) of `0`'s and `1`'s that I'd like to multiply combinations of rows together.

For example, for matrix

```
input = [1 0 1 
         0 0 0 
         1 1 0];
```

and with 2 combinations, I want an output of

```
output = [0 0 0; % (row1*row2)
          1 0 0; % (row1*row3)
          0 0 0] % (row2*row3)
```

Which rows to multiply is dictated by "n Choose 2" (nCk), or all possible combinations of the rows `n` taken `k` at a time. In this case `k=2`.

Currently I am using a loop and it works fine for the 89C2 combinations of rows, but when I run it with 89C3 it takes far too long too run.

What would be the most efficient way to do this program so I can do more than 2 combinations?

Comment: What do you mean more than two combinations? Give an example of the desired result for _n_ Choose 3

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using [**`nchoosek`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html) and [element-wise multiplication](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html).

```
inp = [1 0 1; 0 0 0; 1 1 0];          %Input matrix
C = nchoosek(1:size(inp,1),2);        %Number of rows taken 2 at a time
out = inp(C(:,1),:) .* inp(C(:,2),:); %Multiplying those rows to get the desired output
```

Comment: And if the OP wants to get the product of 3,4,... rows they should edit the last line of code and add more terms?

Comment: @Dev-iL I was about to edit my answer to include more or less the same line with `permute`, `reshape` and `prod` that your answer has at the end. Now thinking of something different

Answer (score 2):

Several things you can do:

1. Use [logical](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logical.html) ("binary") arrays (or even [sparse](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/constructing-sparse-matrices.html) logical arrays) instead of double arrays.
2. Use [optimized combinatorical functions](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?term=permutations%20author%3AJan%20author%3ASimon).
3. [`bitand`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitand.html) or [`and`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/and.html) instead of [`times`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html) (where applicable).
4. **Vectorize**:

   ```
   function out = q44417404(I,k)

   if nargin == 0
     rng(44417404);
     I = randi(2,89,42)-1 == 1;
     k = 3;
   end

   out = permute(prod(reshape(I(nchoosek(1:size(I,1),k).',:).',size(I,2),k,[]),2),[3,1,2]);
   ```